# UINavigationItem: Difference between title and prompt

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I want to use a navigation bar, and I realize that it has `title` and `prompt`.

What is the difference between them?

Comment: How is this related to `xcode`? What have you tried? This question has little to no information or shows any kind of research. Help us help you

Comment: Success help me without me to help you ...

Comment: with the new tagging (uinavigationitem), this is actually a very clear question, and the answers are spot on. Vote to reopen.

Comment: ....and it continually gets upvotes. I hate when people try to say "oh you could have found this out by a little research". Like this is our research and it brought me here, why can't you just answer the question and take the free reputation points.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Although apple documentation does not provide enough information to understand the difference, you could have got answer by little search.

**TitleView** - Used to display main title of you controller.

**Prompt** - Used to provide some additional information to your user.

e.g. You can have title as "Grocery List" with Prompt as "Please select appropriate type"

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You explained very clearly.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

**Here Basic is the title.**

**Sentence in the top portion is the prompt**

Comment: Interesting, my long prompts always end in an ellipsis in iOS 7.